# PolymerDart custom element with two-way binding to Angular.dart model

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I managed to two-way-bind my Angular.dart model to paper elements using the `bind-` syntax:

```html
<paper-input bind-value="item.name"></paper-input>
```

Now I want to create a custom component that can expose a property for two-way binding:

```dart
@CustomTag('px-test')
class PxTest extends PolymerElement {

  @published
  var data = 1;
}
```

used like:

```html
<px-test bind-data="item.data"></px-test>
```

The component gets rendered, and the data-field, referenced in the component template with {{data}} is rendered correctly, but the binding of `data` to `item.data` is not happening, i.e. if `item.data` is 55 the component still renders 1. Angular also tries to create the binding, a watch on `item.data` is created, but the changes are not propagated to `PxTest.data` What do I have to change in `PxTest` to make the binding happening?

Versions: Angular: 1.0, Polymer: 0.15.1+3

Answer (score 1):

I don't know details about how binding between Angular.dart and Polymer.dart works but I suggest you try

```dart
//@published
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)
var data = 1;
```

this way the DOM attribute gets updated too.